# Github Pages Dev Branch?

Tags: github-pages

I currently use the lovely Github Pages to host a website. I would now like to try out some stuff, adding content, new scripts, ... So I have a dev branch in which I do this, and run a local webserver to test it. Once I'm happy with it I can push it to the gh-pages branch for 'release'.

However, I was now wondering. Is it possible to have the dev branch also be reachable anywhere just like the gh-pages branch? This would be very helpful in letting other people try out the new stuff I'm working on without having to risk releasing buggy code to everyone. So basically two gh-pages sites in one repo, one for release one for development.

Is this (or something similar) possible with Github?

Comment: If I remember well, GitHub supports different branch in one repo. So, you could have a 'release' and a 'dev' branch. I don't know If this is what you are asking.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin `gh-pages` is a special branch (published to username.github.io), op is asking if there's another behaving the same

Comment: I know, is for that I said I don't know if this was the answer.

Comment: @ooxi is correct, that's indeed what I'm asking. Or if there is a way to get something that behaves similarly.

Comment: I use a separate repository on github for this purpose. Not answering the question though, because I'm interested in a better way, too

Comment: @ooxi Yea that was also the only workaround I could think of. But you seem to agree it's worth asking if there is a better way. Let's hope there is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So going carefully through the github pages documentation seeking for any solution using the offered functionalty it seems what you are looking for might have been nice but is not available, maybe the closest thing is to have two repositories for example `username.github.io/production` and another one that is forking it like `username.github.io/development` and working on it while pushing changes back to the production one using pull requests or any technique you would prefer

And if you like you can check out my [post](http://leviyehonatan.github.io/coding/starting-a-blog/) and see some techniques of altering your websites, as well jekyll has a `_drafts` directory which allows staging of a post and seeing it before being posted.

Comment: Yea, ooxi suggested this too (see comments on my question). This is now what I'm doing. I'm not going to accept the answer though, leaving it unanswered in case in the future this becomes possible or someone find a way to do it after all. Thank anyway though!

Comment: As of Feb 2023 forking seems to still be the only option

Answer (score 3):

I think any branch can be reached via rawgit.com.

For example, if your user/organization is XYZ, you can reach the `dev` branch for your user/organization jekyll site at:

```
http://rawgit.com/XYZ/XYZ.github.io/dev/_site/index.html
```

Just don't include `_site` in `.gitignore`. You still have to *build* the site locally with `jekyll build`, so it's still not a perfect solution.

Comment: Rawgit is closed as of October 8, 2018.